# How do you make the button have focus in wxPython ScrolledMessageDialog?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I use a simple function to display error messages in a wxPython 4 application. It shows a message and an "OK" button underneath it:

```
dlg = wx.lib.dialogs.ScrolledMessageDialog(self, msg, "Error")
dlg.ShowModal()
```

Problem: when the dialog is presented, input focus is on the message, not the button (at least on macOS). This means hitting return on the keyboard does nothing. It would be more convenient if it had the same effect as clicking on the OK button.

How do I get the **button** to have focus by default when this dialog is presented?

Comment: Using a scrolled message, suggests that a good deal of information has to be displayed. In your example, the message relates to an error. If the focus was on the OK button, then, either people could press enter by accident if they are not concentrating or they could simply not bother to read, what you deem to be information important enough that they should read it. The way that it works now, at least forces them to stop and make a concious decision. How many times have we all been told, the program didn't work, there was an error. What was the error? Don't know I didn't read it.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony You're right – that's a very good point. Thanks to your comments, I changed my code today so that it first presents a regular error dialog, with an optional "help" button, and if the user presses this help button, then it shows more details about the error. So now it is harder to click without thinking, but the focus issue still persists in the 2nd dialog. Thus, I still find myself hoping for a solution to this. Your comment made the interface better, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, why not create your own dialog.
Something along the lines of :

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Custom Dialog",size=(200,100))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Dialog")
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        msg = "Please select one of the options below\n"
        msg += "Help is available if you have encountered this issue\n"
        dlg = MessageDialog(self.panel,msg,"Message Dialog Heading")
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result == wx.ID_HELP:
            print ("Help text was displayed")
        elif dlg.result == wx.ID_OK:
            print ("Ok was Selected")
        elif dlg.result == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            print ("Cancel was Selected")
        else:
            print ("Dialog Exited")
        dlg.Destroy()

class MessageDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, message, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, title)
        ok = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        no = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        help = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_HELP)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, message)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(self.text,1,0,0)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2.Add(ok,0,0,0)
        hbox2.Add(no,0,0,0)
        hbox2.Add(help,0,0,0)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnButton)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnExit)
        self.result = None
        help.SetFocus()

    def OnButton(self,event):
        self.result = event.GetId()
        if event.GetId() == wx.ID_HELP:
            wx.MessageBox('This is my help text dialog', 'Help',wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        self.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,event):
        self.result = None
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a custom dialog window you need to use `wx.Button.SetDefault()` to set the focus on a button, at least on macOS. For example:

```
class MyCustomDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, parent, title=''):
        """"""
        super().__init__(parent, title=title)
        #region ------------------------------------------------------ Widgets
        #--> StaticText
        self.stText = wx.StaticText(
            self, 
            label="The label"
        )
        #--> TextCtrl
        self.tcText = wx.TextCtrl(
            self, 
            value="The values",
            size=(300, 23),
        )
        #--> CheckBox
        self.cbLogP  = wx.CheckBox(self, label='Check A')
        self.cbCorrP = wx.CheckBox(self, label='Check B')
        #--> Buttons
        self.btnOK     = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)

        #### The line below is the one that set the focus on the Ok button ####
        self.btnOK.SetDefault()

        #endregion --------------------------------------------------- Widgets

        #region ------------------------------------------------------- Sizers
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.sizer.Add(self.stText, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tcText, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.box_check = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.box_check.Add(self.cbLogP, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.box_check.Add(self.cbCorrP, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.box_check, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizer_btn = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.sizer_btn.AddButton(self.btnOK)
        self.sizer_btn.AddButton(self.btnCancel)
        self.sizer_btn.Realize()
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer_btn, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        #endregion --------------------------------------------------- Sizers
    #---
#---
```